# Нахождение координаты с учетом направления

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, java, javascript

я жутко извиняюсь! Неправильно нарисовал( Сейчас исправил.
Рисунок номер два не правильный!!! Искомые точки на третьем рисунке ( красные точки ) F,E

Здрасти! Пишу это сообщение в состоянии приближенным к состоянию, в котором есть вероятность нанесения увечий самому себе. я уже неделю читаю книги геометрии и алгебры, но до конца разобраться в своей проблеме не могу. Проблема вот в чем - имея три точки АВС я не могу найти координаты в зависимости от направления. То есть сегодня точка А(300,100), а В(150,50),С(450,150). А завтра А(150,50), а В(300,100),С(450,150). как видно точки имеют хаотичные координаты, но последовательность расчёта углов всегда постоянна ( ищем угол А, потом В, потом С ).
я умею находить и углы и биссектрисы, углы между векторами и косинусы с синусами, НО Я НЕ МОГУ НАХОДИТЬ ИХ ПРАВИЛЬНО! с учётом направления -+
ПОЖАЛУЙСТА обьясните как это делается. Для лучшего понимания нарисовал рисунки.
Точки, которые я не могу найти - F..E..E..
Как находить их я знаю, но у меня они всегда в одном направлении...
[image]

[image]

[image]

> <ABC = acos(AB^2+BC^2-AC^2)/(2*AB*BC)

это находим длину стороны

> AB = sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y2)^2)

это угол...Это я умею, как найти точку D и точки E1,2.. ?

> Такой способ не подойдёт? через
> скалярное произведение?

такой подойдет, но точки D и точки E1,2.. как найти?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<ABC = acos(AB^2+BC^2-AC^2)/(2*AB*BC)

ABC - искомый угол
AB,BC,AC - модули векторов - AB = sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y2)^2)
```

По теореме косинусов.
Если под направлениями подразумеваются углы между векторами и одной из осей, то простым вычитанием.

Comment: Через скалярное произведение надо было. Лучше сразу делать универсально, поверьте моему горькому опыту.

Answer (score 2):

Займёмся археологией :-)

---

Делайте так.

Пускай `A`, `B` и `C` — вершины треугольника.

Легко подсчитать длины сторон: `a = |BC|`, `b = |CA|`, `c = |AB|`. (Ясно, как? Пользуйтесь теоремой Пифагора.)

Теперь, пусть надо найти биссектрису угла `A`. Биссектриса — это луч с началом в точке `A`, а за направляющий вектор пойдёт вектор `(AB / |AB|) + (AC / |AC|)`, то есть `AB / c + AC / b`.

Если вам нужна точка пересечения биссектрис `I`, её прозе всего искать как средневзвешенное вершин:

```
OI = (a * OA + b * OB + c * OC) / (a + b + c)
```

(где `O` — начало кординат.) В координатном виде это выглядит так:

```
x = (a * x1 + b * x2 + c * x3) / (a + b + c)
y = (a * y1 + b * y2 + c * y3) / (a + b + c)
```

(`(x, y)` — координаты точки пересечения биссектрис, `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x3, y3)` — координаты точек `A`, `B`, `C`.)

Ну, и если вам действительно нужен угол с направлением (скорее всего, вам он не нужен, но всё же), воспользуйтесь векторным* произведением:

```
sin (AB, AC) = [AB x AC] / (|AB|*|AC|) =
             = ((x2 - x1)*(y3 - y1) - (x3 - x1)*(y2 - y1)) / (c * b)
```

---

*хорошо, в 2D псевдовекторным

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо, хоть и за "археологический ответ"! Я с этой задачей справился, правда не сразу, для меня эта задача была сложна, но вроде выучил все, что нужно для этого.

Comment: @shatal: Хорошо, что справились сами, значит, задание пошло на пользу :)

Answer (score 0):

А(300,100), В(150,50),С(450,150) => вектора: AB(-150,-50), AC(150,50), BC(300,100) => углы: cos(BAC) = {скалярное произведение, деленное на произведение длин векторов} = (AB, AC) / ( |AB| * |AC| ) = (-150*150 - 50*50) / (sqrt(250) * 10 * sqrt(250) * 10) = -250 / 250 = -1    - нарисовал рисунок, так и есть - развернутый угол!

Такой способ не подойдёт? через скалярное произведение?